# Unable to click on Button due to FrameLayout of NavigtionDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-framelayout

I am unable to click on the "MONDAY" Button due to FrameLayout or ListView (idk What actually is creating problem) of navigation drawer. 
Check out [image: this] image.
What is the possible solution for this?
When i gave the paddingLeft to the button i was able to click on the button.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<!-- TimeTable Button Part
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bMonday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MONDAY"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TUESDAY"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="WEDNESDAY" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="THURSDAY" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="FRIDAY" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="SATURDAY" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFEB3B"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Have your LinearLayout with all these calender options in the framelayout with the id mainContent.

Comment: @Ahmed Yes
Check out the code i have attached in the question

Comment: you cannot assign Namespace URI to both parent as well child remove it from LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

Your main view should be inside of the FrameLayout of the DrawerLayout.
I worked a bit around on your code and i think this should work

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                      android:paddingTop="60dp"
                      tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bMonday"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MONDAY"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TUESDAY"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="WEDNESDAY" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="THURSDAY" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="FRIDAY" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/b6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="SATURDAY" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFEB3B"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:scrollbars="none" /></android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I removed the background and the:

```
<include
android:id="@+id/appBar"
layout="@layout/app_bar" />
```

so I could test the layout.